# Can't get ADB to connect to my Android phone to develop apps on OSX

Tags: android, macos, adb

I recently got a Macbook Pro.  I had an old Macbook and developed Android apps on there with no problem.  I have a Samsung Galaxy S2.  I have installed the Android SDK and Eclipse along with the ADT plugin.  Whenever I connect my device, it says "USB Debugging Enabled" in Android (v4.0.1), but when I run `android-sdk/platform-tools/adb devices` I get the output `0123456789ABCDEF Offline`.  When I unplug my phone and run this, it shows nothing.

I found this thread: [Why is Eclipse and ADB  not recognizing my Android Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594975/why-is-eclipse-and-adb-not-recognizing-my-android-device)

but it is for Linux.  I tried the "Second" steps in the answer from that thread to no avail.  Does anyone know why my phone is showing up like this in adb?

edit:  I just plugged in an old Droid 2 Global and adb connects fine.  Must just be my GS2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to by the ROM I was using (CM9).  I upgraded to CM10 and it works now.

Comment: to kdg123: Which kernel are you running on that GS2? i'm running a pinky-ghost kernel (cm10.1) on a GS1, and ADB always lists the device as offline.

Comment: @Quasaur sorry I don't have the phone anymore, I've moved on to a GS3

Answer (score 2):

I found that I had to both switch to a Powered USB hub AND change cables.  (This was for a Pantech phone connected to a new MacBookPro.)

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I tried this.  It turned out to be the ROM I was using (CM9).  I upgraded to CM10 and it works now.

Answer (score -1):

I just run "adbd" in android device in /data/misc/adb this solved the ofline problem.