# ADB not detecting device samsung i777 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-12.04

this is the first time I am trying to setup adb to connect s2 with my ubuntu desktop. However, when I run `adb devices` and/or `adb usb` it cannot detect the s2. I have followed the following steps:

1. create `udev` rules
2. add to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

But the device is not getting connected while I am in the download/odin mode.

My system is Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and I am using the `adb` pre-packaged with `android studio` running `lsusb` shows me the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```

I have also added the following line to my `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` :

```
# Samsung Galaxy I777
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

and for the sake of full disclosure the permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   95 Jun  2 17:16 51-android.rules
```

also the `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` has the line`0x04e8`

Comment: have you reloaded the rules after adding yours? `udevadm control --reload-rules`

Comment: not really but i did reboot.. dunno whether that reloads the rules or not

Comment: Have you found an answer to your problem, i am having the same

Comment: nope. but then again it could be me. Haven't looked at it for a while. you could try Alex's answer. Though seems like I am messing up something as its not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [universal udev rule](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/04/universal-udev-rule-for-all-android.html), which matches all `adb` and `fastboot` interfaces regardless of vendor ID:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:ff420?:*", MODE="0666"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. will try it out later today and report