# Why ADT Ubuntu does not recognize my device?

Tags: android, ubuntu, driver, adt

I have a Motorola G, and I try to install my programs from DEVELOPED ADT Ubuntu, the problem is that I get the message when I ejercutar application

[image]

From terminal, the following is displayed

```
zhelon@zhelon-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z400:~$ sudo adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

Comment: enabled debugging on you phone?

Comment: enable debugging, installed drivers, and tried unplugging/re-plugging?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Eclipse and ADB  not recognizing my Android Device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594975/why-is-eclipse-and-adb-not-recognizing-my-android-device)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most pragmatic way to fix this would be to run `adb` tools with root access. You are getting a no permissions error, because you need super user privileges to interact with attached devices.

To improve the answer, and alleviate <strike>superfluous</strike> security concerns, you can also run `adb` without root by adding a udev rule for your device. [Instructions here](https://wiki.debian.org/udev).

First, query `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 103: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II]
```

Then create a new rules file and add the rule to it (`/lib/udev/rules.d/10-adb.rules`):

```
# ADB
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTR{idProduct}=="6860", MODE="0600", OWNER="username"
```

Then restart udev, or reboot your computer (recommended).

Comment: No, No, No.  Do not run adb as root.

Comment: Thank very much, that was the solution. "sudo adb kill-server, sudo adb start-server"

Comment: I'm still wondering why people downvote good answers (without leaving comments)

Comment: @ChrisStratton the answer you linked to as a duplicate suggests using `sudo`, i.e. root access?

Comment: No, I did not link to an answer.  But I've just downvoted the *lower rated* answer to the question I linked to, for making that unwise suggestion.  The udev rule answer at the linked question is the **correct** procedure, as explained in the developer docs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The higher rated answer: "...You can also just use `sudo` with ADB, as suggested by \@JeremyD. Doing that makes this file essentially irrelevant..."

Comment: @AlexW : Where is this path located? lib/udev/rules.d/10-adb.rules

Comment: @AlexW : I am not able to find that path in platform tools.

Comment: I am using samsung galaxy s4, the above rule is not showing support for s4

Answer (score 6):

#### I had the same problem and i fixed it using following steps.

- Run Following command.

  ```
  $ sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
  ```
- Add the following lines to it and save it:

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"    
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666"  
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666"
  ```
- Run Following command.

  ```
  $ sudo service udev restart
  ```
- Run Following command.

  ```
  $ sudo killall adb
  ```
- after complete following steps reconnect the phone.

Answer (score 4):

Running adb in root will resolve this issue.

In my case my device does not running as root,

So,

```
/sdk/tools$sudo adb kill-server
```

then

```
/sdk/tools$sudo adb start-server
```

Helped me immediately to find my device in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with an Ideapad A1 Tablet, I fixed installing "android-tools-adb"

```
 sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I had tried to add to the rules.d as suggested but my primary issue came from the mode set on USB PC Connection options. In the case of the LG G tablet, it would not work in Charge Tablet or Media Sync (MTP) modes obviously so if either of those are selected it may not work. It did work in PTP mode though =]. Hope this helps someone dealing with the LG tablets.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```