# Ubuntu 14.04 HTC One device not recognised

Tags: android, ubuntu

This might not be one for this forum, however I'm hoping it's an easy issue for someone who knows more than I.

I've been attempting to root my HTC One M7. I've followed a number of online guides, namely these:-

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zdhyDky2MI
>
> http://androidforums.com/rezound-all-things-root/506466-scottys-noob-friendly-root-guide-start-finish.html

I have enabled developer options, and USB debugging etc without issue. Having started the phone in FASTBOOT USB mode, my ubuntu machine could connect, and I backed up successfully, and also unlocked bootloader.

Having now unlocked the bootloader, my ubuntu 14.04 machine sees my device only when it is switched on normally, and not when it's in FASTBOOT USB mode (as I presume I'll need to be to restore the backup?)

Output of lsusb is as follows:-

> Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bb4:0ff0 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)

So it looks like it's visible somewhere, however the list of devices attached in sudo adb devices is blank, and if I try sudo adb restore backup.ab I get the message adb: unable to connect for backup.

The closest I found was here:-

> [Why ADB Ubuntu does not recognize my device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117590/why-adb-ubuntu-does-not-recognize-my-device)

but this doesn't solve my problem. I've tried restarting adb, and rebooting phone and ubuntu pc.

Having gone to all the trouble of backing up, I'd really like to restore.

If not this forum, then I'd be very grateful of a push in the right direction please?

Cheers,
Jason

Comment: Try a different usb port.  Seriously.

Comment: I may have missed the obvious here. I just tried restoring with the phone in normal mode and it seems to be proceeding.....watch this space.

Comment: @dcow - thanks for the swift response. Will try that if this doesn't work.

Comment: Would you believe it? It restored everything apart from the bit I actually wanted which was the text messages :( Still, better than nothing and I now have some learning to add to my collection. I was rather hoping that adb backup actually backed up everything, but it seems not, unless I'm doing something wrong, which is still possible :)

Comment: oh, yeah adb isn't available when you're in the bootloader.

Comment: I agree with @dcow, adb doesn't work properly in bootloader mode. I usually push all the necessary files to sdcard before going to bootloader mode.

Comment: @DXM you're probably talking about recovery.  AFAIK there is no adb in bootloader--only `fastboot`.